# How does website store cookie's?

Tags: cookies

Im trying to learn why some website store cookie. If I go to website from facebook, some will store and others dont. And how they store cookies from facebook?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A cookie is stored on the client side in your browser.

A good place to learn about the whole process in my opinion: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I know but why when I join in some website from facebook their cookies dont store?

Comment: Do you mean like a standard redirect or some other process?

Comment: No, If I go to cookies in console, some websites i can see cookies from facebook and others I cant. But all these websites I came from facebook to teste.